# Abstract functions in php

Tags: php

I have the next classes in PHP:

```
class CWebApplication extends CApplication {

//...

public function processRequest(){
    //...
}
```

and

```
abstract class CApplication extends CModule {

    abstract public function processRequest();
    //...
```

But it reports the follow error:

```
Fatal error: Class CWebApplication contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (CApplication::processRequest) in /Users/nram/Sites/ryl/framework/web/CWebApplication.php on line 10
```

Comment: Not sure... what you are trying to do definately works in php as expected. There must be something in your setup... Maybe the file where class `CApplication` is defined is a) not saved or b) exists in different versions? Maybe the implementation of ` `CWebApplication::processRequest` is not visible, maybe hidden by a conditional or a syntax error? What if you put a syntax error in there?

Comment: @KevinBrydon why should that matter?

Comment: @arkascha It may be that the answer is in there. Could it be that there is an additional `processRequest` method in CModule with different arguments? Who knows. NRAMs first step should probably be commenting out the abstract `processRequest` method to confirm that the error is still produced.

Comment: If a second version of `ProcessRequest` was defined in `CModule` then the error message would refer to _that_ function... But you are right, it is certainly worth keeping that class in mind as well.

Comment: Is there another function in either class that is declared abstract?

Comment: @arkascha if I delete the abstract function of CApplication, it doesn't show any error. Instead, it only says that I'm using vars undeclared. (makes sense)
I am not using version control. And yes, I've already checked that I saved it and that I was using the right file.
The class CModule doesn't have any abstract function.

Comment: And if you put a syntax error into `CWebApplication::processResult`? Do you get a syntax error or not?

Comment: @arkascha nop. Same error

Comment: @s_ha_dum The error clearly refers to function `CApplication::processResult`, not some other function...

Comment: Aha! That means your method `CWebApplication::processResult` is not interpreted! So ask yourself: why not? Most likely it is hidden somehow... Maybe the class definition is closed beofre? Often happens when the indentation levels are borked...

Comment: I made it available in github. URL : https://github.com/xnramx/RYL

Comment: Sorry, I don't really feel like digging through all that stuff. But one thing jumps to my eyes: you have declared the classes CApplication and CWebApplication _twice_ in that source tree you published. Maybe you accidentially use the wrong class implementation, as I hinted in my very first comment, so that the abstract function really never is implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your code.

In that,

RYL-master\framework\web\CWebApplication.php

actually extends,

RYL-master\framework\base\CApplication.php

In that there it starts with,

```
<?php

/**
 * CWebApplication class file.
 *
 * @author Nuno Morais <nram@nuno-morais.eu>
 *
 */

abstract class CApplication extends CModule {

    private $_basePath;


    abstract public function processRequest();
```

::So you should extend or declare `function processRequest();` in CWebApplication.php.

Hope this helps! :)